# What has a greater performance impact: adding an extra event listener, or needing to query the DOM repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to understand the best way to optimize performance in JavaScript. To simplify, I have some code where a bunch of buttons are each associated with a specific element, and I need to be able to make changes to both the button and its associated element whenever a button is clicked.

I have been told it is better to consolidate event handlers with event delegation where you can. I've also been told if I can avoid querying the DOM over and over for the same element, better to do it just once and store that for later. But in this case, it seems like I need to do one or the other, so I'm wondering which is more costly? Currently I have the following code that runs once to set things up:

```
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  const area = document.querySelector(`#${button.getAttribute('aria-controls')}`);   
        
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // do some things with "area" and "button"
  });
});
```

Obviously this creates an individual listener for each button, so I was thinking I could rewrite it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   if(e.target.classList.contains("button-class")) {
      const area = document.querySelector(`#${e.target.getAttribute('aria-controls')}`);
      // do some things with "area" and "button"
   }
});
```

But is this worth the trade off that now every time a button is clicked I have to query for the associated "area" element again? Does the answer change depending on how many buttons I have or how often they are likely to be clicked? Is there some third answer that is more optimal than either of my solutions? Apologies if this is a really obvious and stupid question, but I've been googling and looking through other Stack Overflow questions and really can't find anything to answer this.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: If it's "a bunch of buttons", you're not querying the *same* element every time so you can't really avoid it. But querying the dom *once* on every click is not repeated querying anyway. The advice to avoid that mostly applies to synchronous loops (where it is measurable) or duplicated code (which is a bad practice anyway).

Comment: @Bergi Each button is paired with one other element, so my understanding is with the first approach those element are queried once when the page loads and references stored, then when the buttons are clicked the existing references can be reused. With the second approach, every button click requires a new query for the associated element.

Comment: @jamescodes Yes, and neither approach really has a noticeable performance impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which is more costly?

As you already noticed, it's a trade-off. The costs you need to compare are respectively

- the execution time taken for initialisation
- the execution time taken of each click handler
- the memory required to keep state

For just a few buttons, that are clicked in normal web flows (and not, say, an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actions_per_minute) testing tool), it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful to know that they are comparable so no obvious better choice. I do understand it's not extremely consequential in my example case, but I'm really trying to understand JavaScript better and make more informed choices, so wanted to know whether more experienced developers consider one option to be significantly more costly.

Comment: @jamescodes Unless we're talking about thousands of elements, or multiple querySelector calls per millisecond, you will not be able to notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better. The impact of having many listeners is far more than a rare DOM query on every click, and you can also cache those lookups. You also probably don't need to do the lookup on `document` and could likely be more specific on what node the lookup should start at, which would make the impact far more trivial than doing a full DOM traversal; you could at least use `.getElementById`, again, to greatly improve performance of that lookup.

I highly doubt you have a situation where they are clicking enough for it to matter, but listener performance impact can be massive and hard to track down and sneak up on you when you aren't expecting it, and do things like silently prevent things from being garbage collected. Minimizing them is more important than caching lookups on a click.